# Pending Intent are not Working as Expected

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, android-notifications

I am having a great trouble with Notification and pending Intent. I am trying to open Chat activity with appropriate user_details from which the message is sent. That's why on Firebase Function I have passed the from_user_id which is the one who is sending the message. I am getting correct logs there in FCM but when I receive a chat notification and open it It opens activity without any userName and messages. It open a new instance of the activity with default values.

```
  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


    String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();


    String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chitchat_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(notification_message);


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        mBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());
}
```

Message payload:

```
  const payload = {
     notification: {
      title: userName,
      body: message,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "com.example.chitchat_TARGET_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION"
     },
     data : {
      from_user_id : from_user_id
     }
    };
```

My Manifest look like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.chitchat">
...        
       <application
            android:name=".ChitChat"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/chitchat_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".GroupChatActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".CallActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name=".ChatActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.chitchat_TARGET_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.chitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
           ...
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="fcm_default_channel" /> <!-- adding -->
            <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
        </application>
        ...

    </manifest>
```

I don't know If I have added some different functions like LifeCycleEvent Listners and EmailVerification for registration has created issues. I am also unable to log the problem I don't know why.
Please, appropriate suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: When this happen, during **Background** or **Foreground**?

Comment: Background. Basically I have restricted it to only receive notifications when status of the user is online i.e when the app is minimized or is closed. In both cases, I can't open the correct activity.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I had already done that only my key value was user_id and I was getting user_id in chat activty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all change `resultIntent.putExtra` inside **onMessageReceived** like:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("from_user_id", from_user_id);
```

And in your **ChatActivity** fetch `user_id` like below:

```
String user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("from_user_id")
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Or change your notification payload:

```
const payload = {
     notification: {
      title: userName,
      body: message,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "com.example.chitchat_TARGET_MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION"
     },
     data : {
      user_id : from_user_id
     }
    };
```

And inside **onMessageReceived** change:

```
String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
```

To

```
String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("user_id");
```

**Reason**: During background, **System** generates the notification without executing your code inside **onMessageReceived**. That's why it puts the extra as it gets from notification payload which is **from_user_id**, that's you send from server.

Comment: I am passing user_id as intent Extra from other activities as well

Comment: Then you have to change payload: data : {
      from_user_id : from_user_id
     }

Comment: data : {
      user_id : from_user_id
     }

Comment: It worked actually. But when the app is in background, it opens only chat activity and when I press back app closes rather than going to the main activity.

Comment: That's a different thing bro, you have to configure this in **ChatActivity** `onBackPressed`

Comment: Can you please help me with that different thing also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200996/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-rehan).

Comment: Please answer this question relevant to your answer in the above post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598605/null-value-in-getstringextra